# Clicking cancel on confirmation box does not cancel the action

Tags: javascript, object, confirm

```
var Main = {
    addConfirmations: function() {
        var e = document.querySelectorAll(".bg-red");
        for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
            e[t].addEventListener("click", function() {
                var e = this.getAttribute("title");
                Main.confirmation(e)
            })
        }
    },
    confirmation: function(e) {
        if (e === null || e.toString().length === 0) {
            e = "Are you sure you want to proceed?"
        }
        return window.confirm(e);
    }
}
window.onload = Main.addConfirmations
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="bg-red" value="Delete">
```

Hi, I have the above function that I use in my website so that it adds a confirmation box to every button which has a red background.. Now this seems to be working such that a confirmation box is popped up whenever I click a red button, however, if I click cancel on the confirmation box it doesn't cancel the action.. This has been annoying me for hours.. I've tried lots of debugging but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the action you are trying to stop?

Comment: e.preventDefault() will stop the action.

Comment: Well you do not cancel the action....

Comment: First, please try to use relevant variable names in coding. Second, handle the confirm response and act accordingly.

`var isOk=Main.confirmation(e);`
`if(isOk===false) event.preventDefault();`

Comment: I don't use jQuery. Is there a JS solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well you return from the confirmation method, but you do nothing with it where you call it.

```js
var Main = {
    addConfirmations: function() {
        var e = document.querySelectorAll(".bg-red");
        for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
            e[t].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                var title = this.getAttribute("title");
                var check = Main.confirmation(title);
                if(!check) {
                    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;          
                }
            }, true);
        }
    },
    confirmation: function (message) {
        if (!message || !message.length) {
            message = "Are you sure you want to proceed?"
        }
        return window.confirm(message);
    }
}
window.onload = Main.addConfirmations
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="bg-red">asdf</a>
```

Comment: Changed it to use preventDefault